IEEE 1394 (firewire) support?
I'm a Linux newbie who just installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 on a PC which had a functioning firewire card installed.  Is there any way I can find support for this card?  Thanks!

This question is similar to: Is firewire still supported by Ubuntu 19.10?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
